# CoreJS to shim or not to shim

Tags: javascript

I'm using https://github.com/zloirock/core-js as an ES6 polyfill for TypeScript 1.5.0 I got from npm

I'm curious what's the difference between:

```
 // Default
 require('core-js');
```

And:

```
 // Shim only
 require('core-js/shim');
```

Another question, what are the other alternatives for ES6 polyfill?

Comment: Please select best answer.

Answer (score 12):

The `shim.js` polyfills all standard ECMAScript methods.
The `index.js` polyfills non-standard methods in addition.

See the required sub modules in the source code:

- [index.js](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/blob/master/index.js) (these are not standard)
- [shim.js](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/blob/master/shim.js) (these are standard)